# Saving information from DataContext in WPF

Tags: wpf, datacontext

I want to save the DataContext "values" at the moment I press the "Save settings" button in the UI, but I really have no idea how to do it. I read a couple of settings from a XML file and then bind them to different controls. Reading some tutorials I implemented the "INotifyPropertyChanged" interface (I also don't know what does exactly) to the "GlobalSettings" class (which is where I get the info from my xml document).

I don't know if I explained myself well, so here is the code...:

XAML Controls:

```
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Header="Multithreading related">
                <CheckBox Content="Use Multithreading" IsEnabled="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Header="Search level related">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Label Content="Select the desired search level:" />
                    <ComboBox Width="200" Text="{Binding ProfileSelected}" x:Name="SearchLevelComboBox">
                        <ComboBoxItem>low</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>medium</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>high</ComboBoxItem>
                    </ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Header="Profiles related">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="UseProfilesCheckbox" IsChecked="{Binding UseProfiles}"
                        Grid.Row="0" Content="Use profiles system" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Label Content="Select the profile you want to edit:" />
                        <ComboBox x:Name="ProfilesComboBox" 
                            Width="200">
                            <!-- Se llena dinamicamente -->
                        </ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="3" Header="General settings">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Select 'Bots' directory:" />
                        <TextBox Width="350" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding DefaultPath}"/>
                        <Button Content="Select..." Margin="10,0,0,0" Padding="5" Width="75"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Username:" />
                        <!-- Binding username to settings -->
                        <TextBox Width="150" Text="{Binding Username}" />
                        <Label Content="(*) Should be the same as your forum username" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
```

GlobalSettings class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SmartGUI.Settings
{
    public class GlobalSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _useMultithreading;
        private string _searchLevel;
        private bool _useProfiles;
        private string _profileSelected;
        private string _defaultPath;
        private string _username;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public bool UseMultithreading
        {
            get
            {
                return _useMultithreading;
            }
            set
            {
                _useMultithreading = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UseMultithreading");
            }
        }
        public string SearchLevel
        {
            get
            {
                return _searchLevel;
            }
            set
            {
                _searchLevel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SearchLevel");
            }
        }
        public bool UseProfiles
        {
            get
            {
                return _useProfiles;
            }
            set
            {
                _useProfiles = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UseProfiles");
            }
        }
        public string ProfileSelected
        {
            get 
            {
                return _profileSelected;
            }
            set
            {
                _profileSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProfileSelected");
            }
        }
        public string DefaultPath
        {
            get
            {
                return _defaultPath;
            }
            set
            {
                _defaultPath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DefaultPath");
            }
        }
        public string Username
        {
            get
            {
                return _username;
            }
            set
            {
                _username = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Username");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">The path you will load the settings from (NOT IMPLEMENTED)</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static GlobalSettings Load(string path = null)
        {
            var settings = new GlobalSettings();

            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists("config.xml"))
                {
                    // Changed the simple linq way to save xml documents to this horrible thing just because
                    // xml.linq doesn't allow to omit the enconding line in the document 

                    var xmlConfig = new XElement("Settings");
                    xmlConfig.Add(new XElement("Multithreading", "false"));
                    xmlConfig.Add(new XElement("Searchlevel", "medium"));
                    xmlConfig.Add(new XElement("UseProfiles", "true"));
                    xmlConfig.Add(new XElement("CurrentProfile", "Defaut"));
                    xmlConfig.Add(new XElement("BotPath", ""));
                    xmlConfig.Add(new XElement("Username", "Unknown"));

                    var xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true };

                    using (XmlWriter xmlOutFile = XmlWriter.Create("config.xml", xmlSettings))
                    {
                        xmlConfig.Save(xmlOutFile);
                    }
                }

                XElement root = XElement.Load("config.xml");

                settings.UseMultithreading = Convert.ToBoolean(root.Element("Multithreading").Value);
                settings.SearchLevel = root.Element("Searchlevel").Value;
                settings.UseProfiles = Convert.ToBoolean(root.Element("UseProfiles").Value);
                settings.ProfileSelected = root.Element("CurrentProfile").Value;
                settings.DefaultPath = root.Element("BotPath").Value;
                settings.Username = root.Element("Username").Value;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Show error maybe
                throw ex;
            }

            return settings;
        }

        public GlobalSettings()
        {

        }

        public void Save()
        {
            try
            {
                var root = new XElement("Settings");
                root.Add(new XElement("Multithreading", UseMultithreading));
                root.Add(new XElement("Searchlevel", SearchLevel));
                root.Add(new XElement("UseProfiles", UseProfiles));
                root.Add(new XElement("CurrentProfile", ProfileSelected));
                root.Add(new XElement("BotPath", DefaultPath));
                root.Add(new XElement("Username", Username));

                var xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true };

                using (XmlWriter xmlOutFile = XmlWriter.Create("config.xml", xmlSettings))
                {
                    root.Save(xmlOutFile);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Show error maybe
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And then in MainWindow.xaml I have:

```
private SmartGUI.Settings.GlobalSettings settings;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    settings = SmartGUI.Settings.GlobalSettings.Load();
    DataContext = settings;
}
```

All those comments are because im not the only one working with the solution, so I comment everything to help my mates to understand.

As you see I can set the values of the controls the first time I load the window, but now I want to save the datacontext into the xml settings file.

I thought replacing config.xml with current controls values might be a dirty solution, but there is for sure a better one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, the `INotifyPropertyChanged` is for bindings. So if you bind a property on your XAML to a property on your ViewModel, and then that property changes, it will fire an event that will eventually make your View update the GUI with the correct value. Without it, you won't see changes happen unless you reload your code.

Regarding saving settings:

Right click on your project, and select `Add -> new item -> Settings File.`
Now, you can have all sort of defaults in that file.
You can load them from the file, save them to the file, and restore the defaults as well, so it's quite handy.
Here's some code that show you how to work with it:

```
// Lets assume you want to save this
string something_to_save = "Remember for next run";

// Assuming you called your setting files: AppSetting.settings
// and that you have a string property called: some_property_you_defined
AppSettings.Default.some_property_you_defined = something_to_save;

// Run this to save the changes
AppSettings.Default.Save();

// Now, close the app, open the app, and then:
string this_is_awesome = AppSettings.Default.some_property_you_defined;

// it should have the value you saved.
```

Comment: Thanks for the INotifyPropertyChanged explanation, but using %AppData% settings is not what Im doing, I used to manage with it but switched to a custom xml file.

Comment: so you just want to add the context to your settings?

Comment: I want to save the current DataContext at the time I press the button "Save Settings", the problem is you can't have something like "DataContext.SelectedProfile" because it inherits from settings in the window constructor...

Answer (score 0):

I have done with saving the DataContext. You just have to call the save method from your Button Click handler like:

```
    private void Save_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
           settings.Save();
    }
```

If you do not want handle the Click Event in the Code behind file. You can use WPF commands for calling the Save method on the GlobalSettings class itself.

You can get the code created by me from the following location...
http://1drv.ms/1q5rqlx